# How to create a nested list of arbitrary depth, D, in which each entry contains D-1 lists

Tags: python, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

Suppose I start with a list as `initial_list = [None] * 4`. By setting `depth = D`, how can I define a routine to create a nested list of arbitrary depth in such way that each entry of the first list admits `x-1` levels, being each level itself a list of other 4 elements. Something that afterwards would allow to slice data as for example `myPrecious[0][0][3][0]`,`myPrecious[3][2][1][0]`,... ?

Comment: **TYPO: x - 1 actually refers to D - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions in a loop:

```py
import copy

def build_list(depth, nb_per_level, fill=0):
  l = [fill for _ in range(nb_per_level)]
  for _ in range(depth):
    l = [copy.deepcopy(l) for _ in range(nb_per_level)]
  return l

>>> build_list(2, 3, 7)
[[[7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]], [[7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]], [[7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7]]]
>>> build_list(1, 5, 7)
[[7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]
>>> build_list(0, 5, 7)
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
>>> my_precious = build_list(3, 4, 7)
>>> my_precious[3][2][1][0]
7
```

Note the importance of `copy.deepcopy(l)` in the list comprehension, rather than just `l`, which makes a copy of the list instead of reusing the same list. Related question about the danger of not making a deepcopy: [List of lists changes reflected across all lists unexpectedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: note that list makes shallow copy, which causes for example `a = build_list(2,2,5)`, `a[0][0][0]=1` to result in `[[[1, 5], [5, 5]], [[1, 5], [5, 5]]]` (even `[1][0][0]` is changed)

Comment: Thanks for the catch @TomášZahradníček